# How to get a value from mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I´m trying to get a value from mongodb aggregate to render in an ejs page through totalAmount, the result that I get is [{"totalAmount":42}] and I want to get only the number in this case, 42

What I have tried is to remove the square bracket with .replace, and I attach .totalAmount to the variable amount, but it doesn't work.

```
app.get("/order", function(req, res) {

var amount;   

 var total = Order.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalAmount: { $sum: '$total' }
    }
 }, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0
    } }]).exec(function (e,d) {
                  console.log(d)
                 amount = JSON.stringify(d)
            });

    Order.find({}, function(err, data) { 
       res.render("order", {ordenItem: data, totalAmount: amount});  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of the aggregate is  [{"totalAmount":42}] as you see it is an array of one element just read it and here an example:

```
app.get("/order", function(req, res) {   

var total = Order.aggregate([{
   $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalAmount: { $sum: '$total' }
   }
  }, {
      $project: {
           _id: 0
     } }]).exec(function (e,doc) {
               console.log(doc);
               let amount = doc[0].totalAmount;
               console.log(doc[0].totalAmount);
               Order.find({}, function(err, data) { 
                  res.render("order", {ordenItem: data, totalAmount: amount});  
               });
       });
 });
```

Comment: Thank´s @Nemer i applied it and it work, so doc[0] looks in  the array the first and only element right?